# How to maintain position of list view row/item?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-imageview

I have a custom `ListView` containing `TextView`, `ImageView`, `Checkbox`. In the `ListView`, nothing should be checked/unchecked as I have to block it based on conditions.

Tasks I am doing:

1. If `Checkbox` is checked then it should show image in `ImageView`.
2. I don't want to make `CheckBox` checkable/enabled based on conditions.

Below is my code for Custom Adapter.

```
    public class CustomAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<POJO> mainDataList;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList< POJO > mainDataList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mainDataList = mainDataList;
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater ) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mainDataList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public POJO getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mainDataList.get(position);
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            private TextView name;
            private ImageView imageView;
            private CheckBox check;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Holder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout_file, null);
                holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Name);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
                holder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.check.setTag(position);

            if (mainDataList.get(position).isEditable()) {
                    holder.check.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.check.setClickable(false);
                } else {
                    holder.check.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.check.setClickable(true);
                }
            }

            holder.name.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getName());
            holder.check.setChecked(mainDataList.get(position).isSelected());

            if (mainDataList.get(position).isSelected())
                        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            else
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(null);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

My problems are:

1. On scroll, `ImageView` shows images randomly irrespective of TRUE condition.
2. On scroll, after every 4-5 list items/rows item get non-checkable (my device shows 4-5 cells/rows/items on screen without scroll) as Item 1 is non-checkable. Simply, it retrieves as per getView() mechanism.

I know this is the problem of maintaining list item position or ListView's recycling on scroll. How to do this?

Comment: @sushildlh Already tried SparseBooleanArray. Please share constructive comments

Comment: you are calling `setImageResource` conditionally: you have to "clear" it on `else` clause, also get rid of that holder stuff: it only messes up the code and its benefits are almost equal to zero

Comment: @pskink Please see my edits

Answer (score 0):

You have a condition such as:

```
if (mainDataList.get(position).isSelected())
           holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

which means that if the model has its property selected to `true` it will set some image resource to the image view. The problem lies beneath the fact, whenever you scroll and `isSelected()` yields `false`, you do not do anything. Because you are re-using the views, you are getting some old views which at some point have had the `isSelected()` to true. It might be currently `false`, but you haven't specified any condition for that.

My suggestion is that you do something in the terms of:

```
if (mainDataList.get(position).isSelected()) 
{
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
} 
else 
{ 
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(null);
}
```